# understanding override and new property

Tags: c#, polymorphism, overriding, new-operator, virtual-inheritance

```
    class Car
    {
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual void CheckName()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

    }

class ConveribleCar : Car
{
    public override string Name { get; set; }

    public override  void CheckName()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("this :{0} , base : {1}", this.Name, base.Name); 
    }

}

class Minivan : Car
{
    public new string Name { get; set; }

    public override void CheckName()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("this :{0} , base : {1}", this.Name, base.Name);
    }
}


and the calling code : 
Car car = new Minivan(){Name = "Minivan"};//using new property
Car car2 = new ConveribleCar(){Name = "Convertible"};//using override property
car.CheckName(); //prints this : Minivan, base : (null or empty)
car2.CheckName(); //prints this : Convertible , base :(null or empty)
```

I understand the theory of virtualization in methods , if you use the keyword new it hiddes the methods in the derived class,
if you use override the new implementation is taken in count and its the one that is used, but I do not understand why this is not happening
with properties , I should expect according to my understanding that the base.Name in car should print "Minivan"  (becasue is hidding the derived Name in class Minivan) ans  this.Name will be null. (as fas as I know)

Also when I inspect the object car in VS car.Name is null even though it prints "Minivan" , this behavior seems really strange to me.
Can anyone give me an explanation of whats going on in the sample code , or Can anyone suggest a better example of how to really see new and override properties working in a proper way so that I can understand, maybe my example is very bad.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The class effectively has **two** properties with the same `Name`. You set one of them. You didn't set the other. Thus it is `null`. Does that make sense? Which _specific_ part is confusing to you.

Comment: When you override it, you extend the existing one, when *newing* it, you hide it. In `VB.Net` is called `Shadowing`. Maybe they chose this name to give a better idea.

Comment: My question would be , whats the difference between using new and override in properties. ok Jimi I hide it but why my instance car prints the this.Name and it is not hidding , it suppose to print base.Name if it is the case I am hidding Name in mi Minivan class , why I have the same behavior ?

Comment: `whats the difference between using new and override in properties.` Do you want one property (i.e. store one value)? Use `override`. Do you want two (i.e. store two different values)? Use `new`. Keep in mind that using `new` is **almost always** the wrong idea. Use `override` by default. _Note that in many cases you don't actually need **either** - just leave it declared in the base class and read / write to as needed from the inheriting class._

Comment: What instance of `Car`? `Car car` is of Type `Minivan`, `Car car2` is of Type `ConveribleCar`, here. *according to my understanding that the base.Name in car should print "Minivan" (because is hiding the derived Name in class Minivan) ans this.Name will be null*. Nope. Who's hiding who?

Comment: "_it hiddes the methods in the derived class_" base class?

Comment: then , when I use Car car = new Minivan() I am hiding Car.Name?, then I must use override if I want Name to be shared between the two classes then why when I go to car2.checkName base.Name does not print anything ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter you override or hide the `Name` property, there will be 2 separate properties with that name, and you can access both implementations in the subclass by `this.Name` and `base.Name`.

To see your expected behaviour, you should probably directly print out `car.Name`, you'll see nothing comes out - it is null. `car` is of compile time type `Car`, so the subclass implementation is not used. It resolves to `Car.Name`, which is not set. Note that printing `car2.Name` prints the overridden property, precisely because that property is overridden.

So why printing `car.Name` gives you null, while printing `this.Name` in `CheckName` doesn't work?

`CheckName` is overridden so the implementation in `Minivan` will be called. Now in the context of the method, `this` is of compile time type `Minivan`, isn't it? So in that context, `this.Name` refers to the subclass implementation of `Name`, hence `Minivan` is printed.

Comment: Okey , so in the second paragraph as I understanding I am hiding Car.Name from Mininvan so thats why I get a null in car.Name because I am using Minivan.Name instead , is this ok? . And then why in car2.CheckName I get null in Base.Name if override its suppose to override the value in the parent class, here my understanding is clear or what I am missing out?

Comment: @Oscar `car.Name` is null because you are accessing `Name` in `Car` class. Only `Minivan.Name` has been set. So yes you are right. Regarding the second half of your comment, overriding does indeed make `car2.Name` resolve to `Convertible.Name`, but in the expression `base.Name`, you are accessing `Car.Name`. Overriding a property doesn't mean you lose all access to it. You can still access the base class implementation by `base.Name`. That's what `base` means.

Comment: Thanks @Sweeper , I almost get everything you say in each comment , but still (sorry if I do not get it) what then would be the difference marking Car.Name with override and new in ConvertibleCar and Minivan , because of what I see and what you have explained to me is the same behavior or almost because car2.Name indeed has "Convertible" meaning I am setting Car.Name opposite in what happens in car.Name which is null  but then why in car2.checkName() gives null  in Base.Name?, So many thanks again in advance I just wanna clear how this works .

Comment: @Oscar `car2.Name` is not null. `car.Name` _is_. That's the difference. The reason why the same results are produced when you do `checkName`, is because  inside `checkName`, hiding no longer takes effect, since `this` is of type `Minivan`. You only see the effect of hiding when you have a subclass object (`Minivan`) stored inside a parent class variable (`Car`). Whereas, with overriding, it doesn't matter what type of the variable is. The method to call is selected only by looking at the type of the object.

Comment: I understand now the difference , now my question is when I set car2.Name="Convertible" according to the object explorer in VS i am setting this property in Car.Name ,but this happens because of the "visibity" that my object has which is visibility of my type Car and not ConvertibleCar, but what is doing is setting the property in ConvertibleCar.Name thats why in Convertible Car base.Name is null, is this correct ? Thanks again in advance

Comment: @Oscar At compile time, yes, `car2` is indeed aof type `Car`. But at runtime, `car2` represents the object of type `ConvertibleCar`, and when you use `.Name`, it sets the `Name` of the convertible car. `Car.Name` is not set. Hiding, however, resolves `car.Name` to be `Car.Name` because it only looks at `car`'s type at compile time.